# How is enabling bitcode for iPhone 5 and above beneficial?

Tags: ios, xcode, arm64, bitcode, app-thinning

Since iPhone 5 and above are 64bit (as 32 bit is deprecated),how is enabling bitcode for iPhone 5 and above beneficial if the application supports iPhone 5 and above only.

Comment: First off, yes you might disable bitcode and 32 bit for app that only target iOS 11 or higher. But bitcode can also includes specific CPU specific optimisations. So mainly why would you disable it?

Answer (score 0):

Bitcode is not about 32 vs 64 bit. It’s about Apple being able to recompile your code with improved optimizations even though they don’t have the source. That is actually more useful the more recent a device is.